# How can I render posts on various "Article" sections of the Bootstrap blog template using Ejs templating, Node and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, bootstrap-5

I'm designing a blog and have chosen to use the Bootstrap Blog example [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/blog/#)

I have Express and Ejs all installed.

I used ejs templating to render the header and footer parts and have also created the form part for creating posts. The header and footer parts for the post creation form page were also rendered using ejs templating.

The challenge I have now, is how to render my posts on the various dummy post (article) sections of the blog template. In other words, when a new post is created, it should be rendered on the various demo sections of the page. That way, various posts that I publish can take up the spaces currently occupied by the dummy posts on the Bootstrap blog template page.

I used the Ejs scriplet tag for writing loops, but they are not working and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Below is a sample of my code for rendering posts on the page.

```
<article class="blog-post">
    <!-- <%= allPostItem.forEach(function(postItem){ %> -->
  
    <h2 class="display-5 link-body-emphasis mb-1" id="demo"><%= moveUp += postItem.postTitle6 %></h2>
    <p class="blog-post-meta"><%= lpostDate %> by <a href="#">Mark</a></p>

    <p>This blog post shows a few different types of content that’s supported and styled with Bootstrap. Basic typography, lists, tables, images, code, and more are all supported as expected.</p>
    <hr>
    <p>This is some additional paragraph placeholder content. It has been written to fill the available space and show how a longer snippet of text affects the surrounding content. We'll repeat it often to keep the demonstration flowing, so be on the lookout for this exact same string of text.</p>
    <h2>Blockquotes</h2>
    <p>This is an example blockquote in action:</p>
    <blockquote class="blockquote">
      <p>Quoted text goes here.</p>
    </blockquote>
    <p>This is some additional paragraph placeholder content. It has been written to fill the available space and show how a longer snippet of text affects the surrounding content. We'll repeat it often to keep the demonstration flowing, so be on the lookout for this exact same string of text.</p>
    <h3>Example lists</h3>
    <p>This is some additional paragraph placeholder content. It's a slightly shorter version of the other highly repetitive body text used throughout. This is an example unordered list:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>First list item</li>
      <li>Second list item with a longer description</li>
      <li>Third list item to close it out</li>
    </ul>
    <p>And this is an ordered list:</p>
    <ol>
      <li>First list item</li>
      <li>Second list item with a longer description</li>
      <li>Third list item to close it out</li>
    </ol>
    <p>And this is a definition list:</p>
    <dl>
      <dt>HyperText Markup Language (HTML)</dt>
      <dd>The language used to describe and define the content of a Web page</dd>
      <dt>Cascading Style Sheets (CSS)</dt>
      <dd>Used to describe the appearance of Web content</dd>
      <dt>JavaScript (JS)</dt>
      <dd>The programming language used to build advanced Web sites and applications</dd>
    </dl>
    <h2>Inline HTML elements</h2>
    <p>HTML defines a long list of available inline tags, a complete list of which can be found on the <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element">Mozilla Developer Network</a>.</p>
    <ul>
      <li><strong>To bold text</strong>, use <code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">&lt;strong&gt;</code>.</li>
      <li><em>To italicize text</em>, use <code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">&lt;em&gt;</code>.</li>
      <li>Abbreviations, like <abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr> should use <code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">&lt;abbr&gt;</code>, with an optional <code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">title</code> attribute for the full phrase.</li>
      <li>Citations, like <cite>— Mark Otto</cite>, should use <code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">&lt;cite&gt;</code>.</li>
      <li><del>Deleted</del> text should use <code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">&lt;del&gt;</code> and <ins>inserted</ins> text should use <code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">&lt;ins&gt;</code>.</li>
      <li>Superscript <sup>text</sup> uses <code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">&lt;sup&gt;</code> and subscript <sub>text</sub> uses <code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">&lt;sub&gt;</code>.</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Most of these elements are styled by browsers with few modifications on our part.</p>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>This is some additional paragraph placeholder content. It has been written to fill the available space and show how a longer snippet of text affects the surrounding content. We'll repeat it often to keep the demonstration flowing, so be on the lookout for this exact same string of text.</p>
    <h3>Sub-heading</h3>
    <p>This is some additional paragraph placeholder content. It has been written to fill the available space and show how a longer snippet of text affects the surrounding content. We'll repeat it often to keep the demonstration flowing, so be on the lookout for this exact same string of text.</p>
    <pre><code>Example code block</code></pre>
    <p>This is some additional paragraph placeholder content. It's a slightly shorter version of the other highly repetitive body text used throughout.</p>
  </article>

  <article class="blog-post">
    <h2 class="display-5 link-body-emphasis mb-1" id="demo"><%= moveUp += postItem.postTitle6 %></h2>
      <!-- <% }); %> -->
```

Here is a plain javascript file I created to use a variable I think can increment the post each time, to render a different new post in another article section each time.

```
let text = "";

var moveUp = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
// alert("I'm here and working");
```

Also, below is my server.js file.

```
    //jshint esversion:6
const express = require ("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
// const ejsLint = require('ejs-lint');
const port = 3000;
const startSuccessMsg = "Server started successfully on port:";

// CONTENT
const postTitle1 = "Title of the largest display post";
const postBody1 = "Shaping a vision of academic success for all students Newcomers to the education discussion might find this puzzling: Hasn’t concern with the academic achievement of every student always topped principals’ agendas? The short answer is, no. Historically, public school principals were seen as school managers, and as recently as two decades ago, high standards were thought to be the province of the college bound. could be defined as entry-level manufacturing work for students who had followed a and low-skilled employment for dropouts. Only in the last few decades has the emphasis shifted to academic expectations for all. Having high expectations for all is one key to closing the achievement gap between advantaged and less advantaged students.";

const dateLong = new Date();
const optionLong = {
  month: "long",
    day: "numeric",
    year: "numeric"
  };
const dateShort = new Date();
const optionShort = {
  month: "short",
    day: "numeric",
  };
const dateOnlyYear = new Date();
const optionOnlyYear = {
    year: "numeric"
    };

const postDateLong = dateLong.toLocaleDateString("en-US", optionLong);
const postDateShort = dateShort.toLocaleDateString("en-US", optionShort);
const pageOnlyYear = dateOnlyYear.toLocaleDateString("en-US", optionOnlyYear);


let allPostItem = [];
// let postItem = {};


app.get("/", function(request, response){
  response.render("index", {repPostTitle1: postTitle1,
    repPostBody1: postBody1, spostDate: postDateShort,
    lpostDate: postDateLong, mainBlogYear: pageOnlyYear,
    allPostItem: allPostItem

  });
  // console.log(allPostItem);
});

app.get("/publish", function(request, response){
  response.render("publish", {mainBlogYear: pageOnlyYear});
});

app.post("/publish", function(request, response){
  const postItem = {
    postTitle6: request.body.post_title

  };
    allPostItem.push(postItem);

  response.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log(startSuccessMsg + " " + port);
});
```

I just hope my question is not complicated.
Please helpful responses will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.